# Dimensionality reduction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pca

I want to reduce the dimension of data to ndim dimensions in MATLAB. I am using `pcares` to reduce dimension but the result (i.e. residuals,reconstructed) has the same dimensions as the data and not `ndim`. How can I project the residuals to `ndim` dimensions only.

```
[residuals,reconstructed] = pcares(X,ndim)
```

Sample code

```
MU = [0 0];
SIGMA = [4/3 2/3; 2/3 4/3];
X = mvnrnd(MU,SIGMA,1000);
[residuals,reconstructed] = pcares(X,1)
```

Now I expect the residuals to have 1 dimensions i.e. the data `X` projected to prime component as I specified it as `pcares(X,1)`. But here both residuals and reconstructed have the same of 2.

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example so we can construct the problem on our end?  Calling `pcares` with `ndim` **should** give you `ndim` projection vectors to reconstruct your data.  Getting it to be the same amount of dimensions as your original data seems rather odd.

Comment: @rayryeng please check the sample code. I want the data to be projected to one dimensions along the principal component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pcares` is doing its job.  If you read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pcares.html), you call the function this way:

```
[RESIDUALS,RECONSTRUCTED] = pcares(X,NDIM);
```

`RESIDUALS` returns the residuals for each data point by retaining the first `NDIM` dimensions of your data and `RECONSTRUCTED` is the reconstructed data using the first `NDIM` principal components.

If you want the **actual** projection vectors, you need to use [`pca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) instead.  You'd call it this way:

```
[coeff,score] = pca(x);
```

In fact, this is what `pcares` does under the hood but it also reconstructs the data for you using the above outputs.  `coeff` returns the principal coefficients for your data while `score` returns the actual projection vectors themselves.  `score` is such that each **column**  is a single projection vector.  It should be noted that these are ordered with respect to dominance as you'd expect with PCA... and so the first column is the most dominant direction, second column second dominant direction, etc.

Once you call the above, you simply index into `coeff` and `score` to retain whatever components you want.  In your case, you just want the first component, and so do this:

```
c = coeff(1);
s = score(:,1);
```

If you want to reconstruct the data given your projection vectors, referring to the second last line of code, it's simply:

```
[coeff,score] = pca(x);
n = size(X,1);
ndim = 1; %// For your case
reconstructed = repmat(mean(X,1),n,1) + score(:,1:ndim)*coeff(:,1:ndim)';
```

The above is basically what `pcares` does under the hood.